# How can I convert Sharepoint Hosted App solution from Sharepoint Online to Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-addin, tasks

I have a **SharePoint Hosted App** solution and it's using for **SharePoint Online**.

[image]

And I also want to use it on **SharePoint 2013**. Therefore, I have changed the Target SharePoint Version to SharePoint 2013. But while I try to build/deploy it, I got some errors about workflows as the image below.

[image]

And with the error code:

> "error XC1033: Could not find member 'ABCTasks' in type
>   'wf://workflow.windows.net/$Activities:SingleTask'." These errors
>   occur with Single Task steps on workflows.

I have tried to search and got some results. But It seems to be not resolved my issue. Please help!

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: I have created workflows by manual again.